# Azure policy is not working for Azure Virtual machine

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-policy

I created a policy definition to have Microsoft Antimalware extension installed on a Windows machine.
When I go to VM > Extension there is no extension:

[image: VM with No Antimalware extension]

However, when I go to VM > Policies and choose the appropriate policies I do not see this VM?

[image: Azure Policy to install Microsoft Antimalware extension]

I executed the below two commands to create the definition and assign policy.

**Definition:**

```
az policy definition create --name 'Microsoft-Antimalware-extension-windows-server' --display-name 'Deploy default Microsoft IaaSAntimalware extension for Windows Server' --description 'This policy deploys a Microsoft IaaSAntimalware extension with a default configuraion when a VM is not configured with the antimalware extension.' --rules 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-policy/master/samples/built-in-policy/deploy-default-antimalware-extension-for-windows-server/azurepolicy.rules.json' --params 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-policy/master/samples/built-in-policy/deploy-default-antimalware-extension-for-windows-server/azurepolicy.parameters.json' --mode All
```

**Assignment:**

```
az policy assignment create --scope /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --policy "Microsoft-Antimalware-extension-windows-server"
```

Also, note, I created the VM manually after  the policy was defined and assigned to the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. Look at policy definition the SKU, Image Offer and Publisher were NOT related to the VM I was creating and deploying hence I could not see it in the "Extension" tab.

I updated the rules JSON file and created a new definition and consequent assignment. All VMs created thereafter have the Extension installed.